# Creating a csv file from controls

Tags: c#, wpf, csv

I have a WPF application, with a form with Questions and Answers. Questions are in a text block and Answer in combobox. The user selects an answer for each question. I need to create a csv file with Questions and Answers. 
I am planning to loop through each control and get the value for question and answer and create the csv file as below:

```
for()
{
 String csv = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, txtQuestion.Text +";" + cbAnswer.Text); 
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test\Samplec.csv", csv);
```

Would this be a good way to go about it?

Comment: Absolutely not. This should be in a bound ItemsControl that you can then iterate over the bound source. You shouldn't be directly manipulating or accessing the UI in WPF unless you absolutley have to.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, **NO** this is not a good way to do this. Accessing the UI directly is a big red flag in WPF for a poor design/implementation.

You should have an items control that is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of some object that holds the question and answer string. Then you would just iterate over the collection:

```
public class QuestionAnswerPair
{
    public String Question { get; set; }
    public String Answer { get; set; }
}

.....

ObservableCollection<QuestionAnswerPair> Questions { get; set; }

.....  

String csv = String.Join(Questions.Select(qAndA => String.Format("{0};{1}\n", qAndA.Question , qAndA.Answer)).ToArray(), ','); 
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test\Samplec.csv", csv);
```

XAML Snippet:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Question}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Answer}"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This generates kind of a weird looking csv file, but it closely matches your code. I'm sure you can figure out the parsing, but feel free to ask if you have questions.